# Insert missing datetime row Sql

Tags: php, mysql, plc

I'm pretty new in php and mysql's coding. I have a sql Measurements table where i put data extracted from a PLC every 15 minutes, with datetime field as primary key and voltage measurements as other fields. 
Ex:

```
Datetime     | v1  | v2  | v3
131003044500 | 403 | 405 | 405
131003050000 | 406 | 408 | 407
131003051500 | 405 | 407 | 406
```

and so on...

When I have a PLC failure, I lost my measurements.
I have to insert ALL the missing row in a day with the correct missing datetime, so the other fields are all 0.

Ex: Missing datetime from 131003080000 to 131003150000

```
131003081500 | 0 | 0 | 0
131003083000 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

etc...

This is for consumption analyses and graph generator.
Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have voltage values somewhere independent of the spolied data? If so, why not combine SELECT & INSERT queries in a usual way to obtain the desired. Maybe there's some inconvenient file format with values and you need php to process it?
On the other hand, if you never did any backups, the data is lost, of course.

Comment: I have to keep track in my DB for every wrong reading from PLC , to obtain  all the 96 readings for a 24 hours/day graph. I haven't any independent values for the voltages, the Voltage fields in DB are 0 for default, to recognize the fault

Comment: Find the answer! 
I've created an empty table called misure2, filled with the missed datatime code.
Then i apply:
 

    INSERT INTO misure (datetime_val, v1, v2, v3)
    SELECT datetime_val, v1, v2, v3
    FROM misure2
    WHERE (datetime_val) NOT IN (SELECT datetime_val FROM misure)